# How to upgrade http protocol TLS1.2 in groovy application

Tags: java, http, grails, groovy, tls1.2

I have groovy on grails 2.5.0 application where i want to set TLS1.2 as its using old TLS version. below code i have set in bootstrap.groovy but seems its not working, any help appreciated.

```
 def init = { servletContext ->

    System.setProperty("com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultProtocol","TLSv12")
    System.setProperty("https.protocols","TLSv1.2")
    println "protocol in bootstrap = "+System.getProperty("https.protocols")
 }
```

But not able to see anything in println statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not all jvm versions support TLS version 1.2. If you are using an oracle jvm, it needs to be a java 1.6.0.121 or later if on java 1.6, java 1.7.95 or later if on java 1.7 *or* any higher version of the jvm (i.e. java 8, java 9 etc).

Assuming that has been taken care of, you need to set the system property:

```
System.properties['jdk.tls.client.protocols'] = 'TLSv1.2'
```

It seems from reading the docs that the `https.protocols` setting should also work, but I know from configuring a large number server jvms using `jdk.tls.client.protocols` that it works. Note that this is to make the server jvms use TLSv1.2 when making requests to the internet, i.e. when they are acting as clients. So we are here talking about configuring the client side of the request. I'm assuming the server side needs to be configured differently.

Also, in your code, the statement:

```
println "protocol in bootstrap = "+System.getProperty("https.protocols")
```

is probably interpreted as

```
println("protocol in bootstrap = ")+System.getProperty("https.protocols")
```

which translates to:

```
null+System.getProperty("https.protocols")
```

since println returns null. This will print `protocol in bootstrap =` but not the system property.

Try explicit parens instead:

```
println("protocol in bootstrap = "+System.getProperty("https.protocols"))
```